# Javascript: How can I transform an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this on a javascript var: (it's a http returned data, and I don't know if it's an array or string - (how can we see that?) - Update: using typeof returned "string", so it's a string.

```
[{"nomeDominio":"gggg.fa"},{"nomeDominio":"rarar.fa"}]
```

How can we pass/transform that, into something like this:

```
["gggg.fa","rarar.fa"]
```

?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: shudnt the keys in key-value pairs be unique?

Comment: good question. I don't know. I'm having always the same keys because this is what I do get from json_encode php function, after a fetch_obj.

Comment: @Kasturi this isn't a KVP in the 'traditional' sense, it's an array of two objects, each of which have a `nomeDominio` property.

Comment: @Katsuri - they are unique within the object. There just happen to be many objects here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is strongly related with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473639/best-way-to-convert-string-to-array-of-object-in-javascript/).

I would suggest reading [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473639/best-way-to-convert-string-to-array-of-object-in-javascript/3582950#3582950) there, as it would really help; and with a little variation, it would just work:

```
var responseString = '[{"nomeDominio":"gggg.fa"},{"nomeDominio":"rarar.fa"}]',
    responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString),
    nombresDeDominio = [];

for(var i in responseObject) {
  nombresDeDominio.push(responseObject[i].nomeDominio)
}
```

Suerte!

Answer (score 9):

You can figure out if is a string or an already parsed object by checking the type of your variable, e.g.:

```
ajax('url', function (response) {
  alert(typeof response);
});
```

You will now figure out if it's a `"string"` or an Array `"object"`.

If it's a string, you can use the `JSON.parse` method as @alcuadrado suggest, otherwise you can simply use the array.

Several answers suggest the use of the `for-in` statement to *iterate* over the array elements, I would discourage you to use it for that.

The `for-in` statement should be used to *enumerate* over object properties, to *iterate* over Arrays or Array-like objects, use a sequential loop as @Ken Redler suggests.

You should really avoid `for-in` for this purpose because:

- The order of enumeration is not guaranteed, properties may not be visited in the numeric order.
- Enumerates also inherited properties.

You can also use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to meet your requirements:

```
var response = [{"nomeDominio":"gggg.fa"},{"nomeDominio":"rarar.fa"}];
var array = response.map(function (item) { return item.nomeDominio; });
// ["gggg.fa", "rarar.fa"]
```

Comment: Great answer bro, I didn't know the difference of sequential loop and for-in in arrays.

The first snippet may look a little confusing though, whats that ajax function? And how can a response give you a parsed array? Thanks (:

Comment: +1 for `map()`. Sadly, you have to make your own (conditional) implementation if you want IE7/8 along for the ride. IE9 has it, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot CMS for your great comment and detail. I have used alcuadrado suggestion because it was a string, after using typeof as suggested.

Comment: @alcuadrado: You're welcome, the `ajax` function is just a library-agnostic example of an Ajax request, which the OP presumably does.

Comment: @Ken: Yeah, IE9 is getting pretty good!, the Sept. 15 they will release another Platform Preview Release :)

Comment: @CMS -- Sweet. Just a few more years to go and we'll all be on the same page!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data always looks like that, you can do something like this:

```
var foo = [{"nomeDominio":"gggg.fa"},{"nomeDominio":"rarar.fa"}];
var newarr = [];
for ( var i=0,j=foo.length;i<j;i++ ) {
    newarr.push( foo[i]['nomeDominio'] );
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUqUV/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really must see much more for in order to use them when I need one. We may not know if a language as a given sintax keyword but, for is almost certain. Thanks a lot for exemplifying with one.

Answer (score 1):

```
function transform(array, f) {
    var ret = [];
    $.each(array, function(index) {
        var v = f.call(this, index);
        if(v) {
            ret.push(v);
        }
    });
    return ret;
}

var result = transform(
    [{"nomeDominio":"gggg.fa"},{"nomeDominio":"rarar.fa"}], 
    function() { return this.nomeDominio; }
);

alert(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's a http returned data, and I don't
>   know if it's an array or string

It's [JSON](http://www.json.org/), and you can use it directly in JavaScript.

If you transform it into your array, you will lose the association key / value ; are you sure it's what you want ?

Comment: Not sure really. I'm loosing all my faith here. The point is to pass this data to a autocomplete plugin and, I don't understand what that plugin wants. I'm completely lost here. It's related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609581/jquery-autocomplete-help-with-code-what-next

X.X

Answer (score 0):

Okay, firstly to get the type of a "thing", use the "typeof" operator (note that the type of an array is an **object**, not 'array'!):

```
var a = "string";
var b = 1;
var c = new Array();
alert(typeof(a)); // string
alert(typeof(b)); // number
alert(typeof(c)); // object
```

To get at the values in the associative array (assuming it is one), you can just loop through it, like so:

```
var d = [{"nomeDominio":"gggg.fa"},{"nomeDominio":"rarar.fa"}];
d["bob"] = "alice";
d["gary"] = "stephen";

for(var key in d) {
    alert(d[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used typeof and I will try not to forget that important note about object been an array. ;) Thanks a lot.